# What triggers the program compatibility assistant

Tags: windows-7

I keep getting the program compatibility assistant window pop up, saying

> This Program might not have installed
>   correctly

whenever I try to download my "setup.exe" file. If I cancel the window, the download continues and completes correctly. I am using [clickonce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ClickOnce) to do this but that may not be relevant.

[image]

It didn't used to happen to start with. But I've downloaded the same file loads of times from various different locations now, and it's happening every time.

Can anyone suggest what is causing this?

Comment: Google for "Windows compatibility shim".

Comment: It looks like a shim may be able to surpress the message. I just want to know what's causing it, and hopefully fix it.

Comment: Did you choose "This program installed correctly"? Not sure but this may reset the compatibility setting for that file name.

Comment: You are right. Clicking that does stop the message appearing again. But it doesn't really answer my question of why it is happening in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

You're asking why the warning was continually popping up even after clicking "This program is installed correctly" made the warning stop? The trigger causing the warning was never changed so the warning was triggered every time...I think that's why... :-) It's probably simply a really old application that 7 has decided will need some extra help to run successfully.

You didn't mention if you have local administrator rights to this box. Wouldn't surprise me if GPOs could cause issues.

I did find this KB article. It's about Vista but has some information about it:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/931709

Comment: If I click "This program is installed correctly", the warning stops appearing. I just wanted to know why the popup appeared in the first place.